# Implementing the scott T method

Tags: c

I've trying to implement a math formal to convert a 3 phase system into 2 phases, using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265358979


void getAngle( float  xValue , float  yValue, float zValue){
     float x = 0.0;
     float y = 0.0;
     float z = 0.0;
     double rad_angle =0.0;
     double  angle =0 ;
     double zaehler = 0.0;
     double nenner = 0.0;
     z=xValue;
     y=yValue;
     x=zValue;

     printf(" Getangle \n" );
     printf(" X = %lf , [BY = %lf , Z = %lf \n " , x,y,z);
     zaehler =z-x;
     nenner  = ((y-x) -((x-z)/2-(z-y)/2))*(2*sqrt(3));
     printf (" the sin value is  :  %lf  \n" , zaehler);
     printf ("  the cos value is  : %lf \n",nenner);
     rad_angle = atan2(nenner,zaehler);
     printf("Radangle = %lf \n",rad_angle);
     angle =( rad_angle  * 180/PI);
     printf("Angle in degree   = %lf \n",angle);
}

void setAngle(float angle ){
   float x = 0 ;
   float y = 0 ;
   float z = 0 ;
   printf(" the given angle is : %lf \n",angle);
   angle = angle *PI/180;
   x = sin(angle);
   y = sin(angle+(120* (PI/180.0)));
   z = sin(angle+(240* (PI/180.0)));
   printf(" Set  angle \n" );
   printf(" the x value  : %f ,\n the y value : %f ,\n the z value :%f ",x,y,z);
   getAngle(x,y,z);
}

int main (){
    float angle = 0;
    while (1){
        printf(" angle in Degrees \n");
        scanf("%f" ,&angle);
        printf("  sinus angle : %f", sin(angle*PI/180));
        setAngle(angle);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here is what I'm trying to implement:

[image: equation]

I never get the angle that I give back.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nenner  = (y -((x+z)/2))*(2/sqrt(3));

Comment: thaks for your help, but it doens't work you could test it on your device !

Comment: any idea why this isn't working, or is the rule to get the  angle value wrong ?

Comment: It took me a bit to figure this out. In setAngle(), x , y, and z are the relationships between S1, S2 and S3, not the values of S1, S2 and S3. So zaehler is simply x (since x = sin(angle) = S3 - S1).

Comment: sorry but I need you to explain I've been setting the whole day on this still didn't figure it out

Comment: is nenner that sqrt(3) cos(angle) = y-z;

Comment: I've tried it but still don't get the correct angle, I've read the AD explanation sheet they said  that for instance x = sin(angle) , angle y-z = sqrt(3)cos(angle)

Comment: Go back to the app note, and look at equations 1 to 3. They do not describe the voltage at any of the 3 points - they describe the differences in the voltages. So your setAngle() is not correct. x,y and z are not the S1, S2 and S3 in your diagram.

Answer (score 0):

here it is fixed up, I had to chage the order of x,y,z and fix the nenner formula.

```
void getAngle( float  xValue , float  yValue, float zValue){
     float x = 0.0;
     float y = 0.0;
     float z = 0.0;
     float rad_angle =0.0;
     float  angle =0 ;
     float zaehler = 0.0;
     float nenner = 0.0;
     y=xValue;
     z=yValue;
     x=zValue;

     printf(" Getangle \n" );
     printf(" X = %lf , [BY = %lf , Z = %lf \n " , x,y,z);
     zaehler =z-x;
     nenner  = (y -((x+z)/2))*(2/sqrt(3)); 
     printf (" the sin value is  :  %lf  \n" , zaehler);
     printf ("  the cos value is  : %lf \n",nenner);
     rad_angle = atan2(nenner,zaehler);
     printf("Radangle = %lf \n",rad_angle);
     angle =( rad_angle  * 180/PI);
     printf("Angle in degree   = %lf \n",angle);
}
```